# How to set paddding of Icon of menu item in Master detail page?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

How I can give the margin to the menu icon from left. I am using Master detail page for showing menu and contents. [image]

Comment: What dimension of your burger button icon?

Comment: its 32 X 32 png image type

Comment: Have you tried to use smaller icon, how is it look? (15x15, for example)

Comment: It will nok look good if we use 15x15. or other small icons. Is there no way to manage the padding of it?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/MasterDetailPage) sample. It look nice there.